# loading more items without scrolling nor pressing 'see more' like in facebook with JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api, dom

How can I load more page contenant in facebook, without pressing 'see more' button using javascript ?

for example in facebook groups, if I want to view all the group members I shall go to members tab and press 'see more' until the end of the members..

I'm working on creating a browser extension that will allow me to extract some info from the members page, I know that I can extract names from facebook graph api, but I'm looking for extracting more info such who added those members.. by scanning the source code of that page.

So now I'm facing 'how to automatically load the whole members page contenant ?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily trigger click events on the button like this:

```
<button id='load-more-button'>Load More</button>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#load-more-button').click(); 
</script>
```

If you want to repeat the proccess untill its end i guess this would do the job:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    $("#load-more-button").click();
},3000);
```